Im having problems setting up selenium with java in eclipse
I started to learn selenium but im having issues running my programm, this is my error: and this is my code
package SoftPlan;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //cesta k webdriveru v mojom pc
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\DATA\\Desktop\\selenium\\chrome_driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        //vytvorenie 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //tu zadam kam sa chcem dostat
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/softplan_slovakia/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}

Not sure what to do as im new to importing packages.
I followed a youtobe video on how to start, and i downloded webdriver for chrome, selenium server 4.19.1 and selenium java 4.19.1

Does the YouTube video tell to create a module-info.java file and is it about Selenium 4.19.1?
